# Tuple and recursive list conversion

Tags: python, tuples, sequence

A recursive list is represented by a chain of pairs. The first element of each pair is an element in the list, while the second is a pair that represents the rest of the list. The second element of the final pair is None, which indicates that the list has ended. We can construct this structure using a nested tuple literal. Example:

> > > (1, (2, (3, (4, None))))

So far, I've created a method that converts a tuple of values or the value None into a corresponding rlist. The method is called to_rlist(items). Example:

```
>>> to_rlist((1, (0, 2), (), 3))
(1, ((0, (2, None)), (None, (3, None))))
```

How do I write the inverse of to_rlist, a function that takes an rlist as input and returns the corresponding tuple? The method should be called to_tuple(parameter). Example of what should happen:

```
>>> x = to_rlist((1, (0, 2), (), 3)) 
>>> to_tuple(x)
(1, (0, 2), (), 3)
```

Note: The method to_rlist works as intended.

This is what I have so far:

```
def to_tuple(L):
    if not could_be_rlist(L):         
        return (L,)
    x, y = L
    if not x is None and not type(x) is tuple and y is None:         
        return (x,)     
    elif x is None and not y is None:         
        return ((),) + to_tuple(y)
    elif not x is None and not y is None:         
        return to_tuple(x) + to_tuple(y)
```

Which gives me the following result (which is incorrect):

```
>>> x = to_rlist((1, (0, 2), (), 3)) 
>>> to_tuple(x)
(1, 0, 2, (), 3)
```

How can I fix my method to return a nested tuple properly?

Comment: A recursive list is one which contains a reference to itself.

Comment: @wim It could also mean "a list type defined in terms of itself" in which case it would fit. (It's also probably the term the assignment uses, another reason why it can stay.)

Comment: @user1140118: Stack Overflow is not a "do (parts of) my homework for me" site. You should get started on the function on your own, and post questions about *specific* problems you're having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def to_list(x):
    if x == None:
        return ()
    if type(x) != tuple:
        return x
    a, b = x
    return (to_list(a),) + to_list(b)
```

Comment: 1. use `x is None` for comparisons against singleton  2. use `isinstance` for type checks, so that the code still works with inherited classes  3. when you see the `homework` tag, don't just post a solution.  help the student work out what area needs improvement in their own work.

Comment: I tried the solution but can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for my HW ;)

```
def to_rlist(items):
    r = empty_rlist
    for i in items[::-1]:
        if is_tuple(i): r1 = to_rlist(i)
        else: r1 = i
        r = make_rlist(r1,r)
    return r
```

Comment: What is empty_rlist and what is make_rlist ?

Comment: Dear user, your answer seems to be useful. Although, it is important to first provide some solution description. We would like to know some motivation, as well as a simple, yet complete, explanation regarding your problem solution.